# Ping connected Clients to VPN tunnel PPTP

Tags: linux, networking, centos, vpn, pptp

I have set up a vpn server on `CentOS 6` (PPTP) following [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-setup-your-own-vpn-with-pptp) guide...

***Server End***

*ifconfig*

```
ppp0      Link encap:Point-to-Point Protocol 
          inet addr:192.168.1.15  P-t-P:192.168.1.200  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1396  Metric:1
          RX packets:5005 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:4486 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:3
          RX bytes:560341 (547.2 KiB)  TX bytes:2200506 (2.0 MiB)

ppp1      Link encap:Point-to-Point Protocol 
          inet addr:192.168.1.15  P-t-P:192.168.1.201  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1496  Metric:1
          RX packets:478 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:472 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:3
          RX bytes:30799 (30.0 KiB)  TX bytes:60845 (59.4 KiB)
```

*route -n*

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
192.168.1.201   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 ppp1
192.168.1.200   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 ppp0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth0
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
```

i have two clients successfully connected to the tunnel one is linux machine running CentOS and the other is an android device, both are assigned ips `192.168.1.201` and `192.168.1.200` respectively.

Now from my CentOS client (192.168.1.201) i cannot ping the android device (192.168.1.200), adding the route 
    ip route add 192.168.1.0  netmask 255.255.255.255 dev ppp0

doesn't help also...

Also plz guide how can i route all my CentOS client traffic through the tunnel because when i check my public ip it shows the same ip of client's route before and after connecting to the vpn server

**CentOS client**

*ifconfig*

```
ppp0      Link encap:Point-to-Point Protocol  
          inet addr:192.168.1.201  P-t-P:192.168.1.15  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1496  Metric:1
          RX packets:239 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:239 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:3 
          RX bytes:19632 (19.1 KiB)  TX bytes:19638 (19.1 KiB)
```

*route -n*

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 ppp0
122.121.34.333  192.168.1.1     255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 wlan0
192.168.1.15    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 ppp0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     2      0        0 wlan0
192.168.122.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 virbr0
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan0
```

where `122.121.34.333` is the public ip of the vpn server

Regards.

Comment: any suggestions??

Comment: Hey, from what I see in your routing table you used the same subnet for your pptp tunnel as your local lan? Try starting with using a different subnet.

Comment: @Goez tnx for your time, can you guide me a bit where i had to make the changes, in the `ppp-options`? i guess...